# Renamed Activity and now it won't launch

Tags: android, android-activity

I renamed an Activity using Eclipse's refactor menu.

I cleaned the project and recompiled.

When I go to launch the Activity, the lines execute with no error.

```
Intent launchScreen = new Intent(this, ActivityMyScreen.class);
startActivityForResult(launchScreen, REQUEST_MYSCREEN);
```

I set a breakpoint in the onCreate method of the Activity being launched and it is never reached.

The only information Eclipse gives to me is in the LogCat, where it says the following every time startActivityForResult is called...

`Initializing inflate state...`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the manifest file to make sure the name was updated in there?

Comment: Yes.  I did that.  I'm pretty sure it would crash if I didn't.

Comment: Was it not properly renamed in some location like Nik said? If so, in which file was it not renamed?

Comment: duplicate of.  Answer is Its android tools rename app.  Refactoring alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reference to the old activity name somewhere in your project.  Probably the project's manifest file, but it may be elsewhere.

The easiest way to check would be to use Eclipse's search functionality to search the whole project for references to the old activity name, and correct any that it finds.

In my experience Eclipse does not always detect when it needs to rebuild the project in this situation, so it's also a good idea to clean and start a fresh build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie, but I found checking (choosing) the following options did it for me without a glitch.

- Update similarly named variables and methods (Be aware that you need to also choose Find exact names within the configure menu/link)
- Update full qualified names in non-Java text files

Eclipse shows a preview of changes in all non-Java (manifest, etc.) files before committing the change.